# R dplyr conditional sum with dynamic conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to calculate column "sum_other_users_30d" from the following dataset (example):

```
id user count date_start date_current **sum_other_users_30d**
1    1     3 2015-01-01   2015-01-07                  16
1    1     2 2015-01-01   2015-01-10                  16
1    1     5 2015-01-01   2015-01-20                  16
1    1     1 2015-01-01   2015-02-22                  16
1    2     1 2015-02-02   2015-01-15                   3
1    2     1 2015-02-02   2015-01-10                   3
1    2     6 2015-02-02   2015-01-30                   3
1    2     2 2015-02-02   2015-02-22                   3
1    3     1 2015-01-16   2015-01-17                  14
1    3     1 2015-01-16   2015-01-31                  14
1    3     6 2015-01-16   2015-01-30                  14
1    3     2 2015-01-16   2015-02-22                  14
```

The value of sum_other_users_30d for each observation is a sum of count of other user values (user != user in current obs), with date_current within 30 days from a given date_start (date_current - 30 <= date_start in current obs).

For example, in first line the sum of 16 is made up of following count values:

```
id user count date_start date_current sum_other_users_30d
1    2     1 2015-02-02   2015-01-15                   3
1    2     1 2015-02-02   2015-01-10                   3
1    2     6 2015-02-02   2015-01-30                   3
1    3     1 2015-01-16   2015-01-17                  14
1    3     1 2015-01-16   2015-01-31                  14
1    3     6 2015-01-16   2015-01-30                  14
```

I'm trying to do this in dplyr with mutate(), but I can't find a way to reference sum conditions to particular observation values (user unequal current user etc). 
I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: Something like this `df %>% group_by(user) %>% mutate(sum_other = sum(df %>% filter(abs(df$date_current - date_start) <= 30, user != df$user) %>% select_('count')))` maybe? I'm not quite sure how you want your date filtering arranged, but if you use `$`-notation, you can refer to the whole dataset, whereas bare column names just refer to the group.

Comment: thanks, nice workaround :) there seems to be a problem with setting a different condition, for example taking only past observations (df$date_current - date_start < 0) doesn't seem to work: Error: only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables.  Could it be because of no obs meeting the criteria? if so, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: There are no dates that work for the first user, so `filter` doesn't return any rows for it, so `sum` has nothing to sum. If you use subset notation instead of the nested chain, it works: `df %>% group_by(user) %>% mutate(sum_other = sum(df[date_start > df$date_current & user != df$user,'count']))`